# How are the guards recruited?

Tags: squid-game

We see that in *Squid Game*, there are a large number of guards who oversee the games. Of course, we are given some idea of how the contestants are recruited—they are extensively surveilled and then psychologically profiled through a game.

However, the recruitment process for the guards is arguably at least as important: they certainly must be absolutely loyal and unwilling to reveal the secret of the game or attempt to steal the money, able to stand up to a work environment that is at turns extremely tedious and dangerous, as well as cold-blooded enough to kill any contestant on the drop of a hat or even their fellows if their leader so orders it.

How does the organization select the guards?

Comment: Strong vibes of Stanford Prison Experiment. The guards are as much surveilled and under strict orders as the contestants.

Answer (score 3):

There's an interesting theory regarding the first game Gi-hun is offered to play at the train station, called **Djaki.** Note that there is a *blue card* and a *red card*. Gi-hun chooses the **blue card** and he gets selected as a **player** (cyan outfits). The theory is that, had he chosen the **red card**, he would have been recruited as a **guard** (magenta outfits). This would explain why the guards are also being regulated in some manner (numbered rooms, time schedules, no talking policy, no revelation of identity).

[Source](https://screenrant.com/squid-game-best-fan-theories/)

Comment: That seems extremely logical.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but has some problems. Picking a color is basically random, with a nearly equal chance for picking one of the cards. Yet the attrition rate of guards is much lower than of the players. Hundreds of players die every season, yet in this game only a handful of guards died, even that in special circumstances, so there might be many games where not a single guard dies. The question now would be, if the guards return next year. If not, then they also need massive recruitment for them. But the organ harvesting ring hints that guards might be employed for more than one season.

Comment: @vsz: Note that the officers (squares) and grunts (circles) are not alike. The grunts might be replaced constantly. Neither 28 or the assumed identity of 29 were hinted at being involved for a long time they were merely divers/couriers and treated as lessers. Btw, I'm unsure about guards (triangles). I would guess that seniority is valued as they are the ones carrying most weapons.

Comment: Also note, though the color selection is seemingly random: who's to say every potential recruit is even given a color choice?  The Djaki theory could still hold true if color selection is no longer an option once all player or guard openings have been filled.  Likewise, color selections past the current game limit could theoretically be applied to the next game. Though I favor the previous idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no certain information revealed, so unless there will be a second season explaining it, we can never know for certain.

**However, there are many strong hints.**

One such very strong hint explains how they are loyal and why they don't mind killing unarmed innocents: both the host (on his deathbed) and the front man (when executing the doctor for cheating) explain an ideology they strongly believe in: **they believe they're giving a fair second chance to people whose lives were already beyond saving in the outside world.** This ideology can be like a central doctrine of a cult. (Yes, the games were created by the founders purely for their own entertainment, but creating this ideology is a good excuse for them to suppress any traces of conscience they might have had, or their employees might develop)

Another key point is that the contestants are given a fair choice. Everyone is there on their own accord, they aren't forcing anyone to compete, and they can have a fair vote at any time to stop the games. Of course, we can call them hypocrites if we want (circumstances of the player's lives force them into continuing), but that doesn't matter. All that matters is that the organizers strongly believe that they're not responsible for the player's deaths, because they are there on their own free choice. This means that any of the staff who might have conscience problems, can use the above justification to not feel guilty.

We should not forget the Milgram experiment, and how prone guards in POW and forced labor camps were to mistreat inmates. Especially if they can find an ideological justification to see them as subhuman. And here the players are people who are already "beyond saving" in the outside world. They will likely get killed by loan sharks, or commit suicide pretty soon. They can be considered as being *already dead*. Remember, some guards referred to the contestants as "zombies". So if they're already dead, why should the guards feel guilty about shooting them? Especially if the players are there on their own free choice?

So, where can they get new recruits?

- we see (if I remember correctly) 3 unmasked lower-rank guards, and all of them are very young. They can be recruited/kidnapped as children, probably as orphans, and raised/brainwashed that way. The organizers are strong believers of the "free choice" doctrine, even if that free choice is only "free" from a certain viewpoint, but if they really recruit orphans who have nowhere else to go, they are "providing them an opportunity" just like they do with the players.
- higher ranking guards might be strong believers of the ideology presented above. It's like high-ranking people in a cult, some might be there for strongly believing the cult's teaching, others just for enjoying being in power over people they can feel superior towards. The organizers of the games are some of the richest and most influential people on the planet, I won't be surprised if they were also owned stakes in some cults.
- former winners are not enough to make up the full roster, many are unlikely to want to join, and it's unlikely that they are forced to do so, given the central doctrine of "free choice". But some of the higher ranking staff can be former winners, just as the Front Man is a former winner.
- a very likely pool of candidates is made up of those who voted to leave and didn't return. In the current year, there were 14 people who decided not to return, and the Front Man is seen giving the order that they should be kept under surveillance. Remember, the candidates are all in a desperate situation, with debts they are incapable of ever repaying. It is very likely that when new positions open up, they are approached and given the opportunity to join the staff. They aren't forced, but they don't really have any choice besides getting killed by the loan sharks they are indebted to or dying of starvation. They are desperate, and probably were on the verge of choosing to return but chickened out at the last moment because they were too afraid of dying suddenly in the game. But they *are* desperate, remember that 93% of the players decided to return to the games on their own free will even after they learned that they get killed if they don't win. The other 7% is equally desperate, so if given a choice to be member of the staff, where they have a much higher chance of survival, they'll be eager to accept.

Comment: This is such a poor conceived answer.   They meet up once a year.   You don't brainwash people and have them meet up with you for a few weeks once a year.   There is absolutely no justification of the guards.   There is no reason why the guards couldn't overtake 1 leader and take the cash.   All of your examples are extremely off base.   They could possibly come up with reasoning in season 2 - it surely won't be the opinions you have here.

Comment: *"There is no reason why the guards couldn't overtake 1 leader and take the cash"* - the winner receives the money into a bank account, immediately after the final round. The money in the room might as well be fake, only for illustration, there's no reason to keep the same amount of money twice. And it's a big, powerful international organization, with deep connections if they can do so much surveillance and not get caught. Trying to double-cross the boss will get any mutineer hunted down. There isn't only one leader, the Front Man is only the organizer of the local event.

Comment: No.   There is no reason to believe the money is fake.   It is intimated from player 1 that he has so much money he doesn't care.   There is nothing in the entire season that even alludes to anyone on the "management" team other than the leader being on the island.   So there might be surveillance and whatever but there is only 1 guy to kill to get the money.    I am sure the writers will backtrack to try to give some explanation but right now you just have to accept everything with no semblance of reality.

Comment: @blankip I'm not sure on the money thing, but I'm sure about the *"it's not only one guy"* thing. They hold the games in other countries too. And the owners need both political and criminal underworld connections to have a chance of pulling it all off. It has to be a bigger conspiracy, having many agents infiltrating society, in order to keep surveillance on so many candidates. And if it's so easy to do that *"there is only 1 guy to kill to get the money"* why does it not happen to IRL dictators that a bodyguard kills him and takes over? A power hierarchy is more complicated than that.

Comment: There's 1 guy at that location.   So if the guards kill that 1 guy - the leader... a swat team from Egypt flies in and does what?    I don't get why you are getting this.   This could never happen - ever.   You have to accept the holes in the premise.      Could this work with 5 guards... no but maybe its more believable.   But with this many guards... ummm... no.   And the fact that they are early 20s... makes your premise weaker.   These guys would be all over the place and very hard to control.

Comment: @blankip : somehow this question is not *"How likely is the premise of the movie to actually happen in real life exactly as it happened in the movie?"*. Why are you trying to answer *that* in the comment sections of multiple questions??

Comment: same reason you have a very ill conceived answer that is completely opinion.

Comment: @blankip And there's nothing stopping bank employees from robbing the bank themselves  The Squid Game guards would have to organize a large conspiracy without anyone betraying it, get the money off the island, and then spend the rest of their lives hiding from the organizers. Also, they would have to worry about whether this is a sting operation, and whether there's a sub-conspiracy that they're not in on to kill the rest of the conspiracy so they have to share the money among fewer people.

Comment: @Acccumulation - what are you talking about?   5 guys can take the money and be off the island in a couple hours easy.   The rest of the guards are uninformed in their quarters or working where ever.   Bank guards are not doing something highly illegal.   So yes they could rob the bank but they would chance prison.   These guards go to prison if they are caught.  Your comment illustrates my point not yours.  Hmmm working for a company that shoots people daily or hiding out with millions... Hmmmm...

Comment: @blankip : from the looks of it, from how they can monitor so many people (including the main character boarding a plane), how they know so many personal details about every contestant, how they managed to stay hidden for such a long time, it is clear that they're a gigantic world-spanning conspiracy, with deep connections with the most powerful and influential people of the world. It's even shown that Korea is not the only place they're hosting these games. It's not just a lone guy in a mask. It's a global, Illuminati-like super organization. Do you think you could double-cross them and live?

Comment: @vsz - I get that.   That's what makes it unrealistic.   How unrealistic it is has really no bearing on the conversation.   Crooks/debtors will still pick stealing and hiding vs doing the games.    Let's just say a guard understood this...    It would only make them more careful not deter them because they would have to think they are dead at any time, stealing the loot or not.   But again there is no way to have an organization this big and widespread and a secret - again suspend all thoughts of reality.

Comment: @blankip : yeah, I get it, you don't like the premise of the show. But do you really have to repeat that over and over again, in multiple comment sections at multiple questions? This site is neither a blog, nor a movie relieve site.

Comment: @blankip: There are multiple games a year, as evidenced by the cop walking through the archives, with multiple aisles worth of records. It seems a monthly thing. Inbetween prep and player acquisition, that would be a non-stop activity.

Comment: IIRC the "zombie" was in reference to a player who should be dead but survived. I did not catch any reference to _every_ player being referred to as a zombie.

Comment: @Flater - no the guards clearly only come to the game when it is about to start.   There may be communication but the guards pick up the players to start the game and put them on the boat.   There is nothing about the guards living at the island all year around or anything that would support that.

Comment: @blankip: Just because the guards pick up the players does not mean that they did not come from the island.

Comment: @Flater - yes guards come to and from the island in a pack of 100 minivans undetected.   Hundreds of people go missing all at once (much more conceivable if they randomly went missing) and these guards according to you - no hint on the show - all got got out a huge boat (ferry) that is stationed outside the island holding a fleet of minivans that goes undetected until the leader asks the guards to get out of their cell and go capture the contestants all in one night.   So the boat goes where ever, sits on the dock, all of the minivans leave ... cont...

Comment: and then the minivans go to random locations throughout the country, 400+ people are captured, sedated, and not one ounce of suspicion (massive massive luck), then all of the minvans make their way back to the dock and go onto the ship.   No port authority notices all of the minivans, no one checks the ship, no one reports the missing people... nothing... and the guards not having left the island - according to you - ALL do exactly as they were told, don't stop to see an ex-gf or eat out, grab their hostages and go straight back... come on!